# Can I add the Star rating in email template?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a template for product overview using PHP and send the email to the user. I want to include Star Rating in the email so user can rate the product.
Any help?

Currently I am using below code and I want to store everything after submit button or form submission, In that case how can I do this?

$body = '

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=1">
        <img src="star.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=2">
        <img src="star.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=3">
        <img src="star.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=4">
        <img src="star.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=5">
        <img src="star.jpg" />
    </a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio 1 value" checked>
        <label for="radio1">Yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radio 2 value">
        <label for="radio2">No</label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
        <textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="textarea" id="textarea">More text</textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="Submit">
         Submit
     </button>
  </div>
</form>';
```

Comment: "The" star rating? As in a specific plugin? Or just generally?

Comment: As I have successfully set up on view page through this plugin:-
http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating-demo-basic-usage

 but not able to include in email template. because I have create template on php code.

Comment: You probably will not be able to use the plugin directly, as it requires JavaScript, and JavaScript will *never* work. You'd have to make your own solution - a series of clickable images linking to URLs that save a vote to the database when clicked.

Comment: Agree, But I want to store all the information after submit button.

Comment: You won't be able to have it use a submit button like that.

Comment: Yes right! But my requirement just like code above. so can you please help me out to add the star rating.

Comment: **You cannot use the code above. It will not work like that in HTML email.** You are going to have to convey to your client that *some* things are simply not possible in emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use Javascript in emails, so you will have to do a workaround.
You could for example add 5 images of stars, each linked to a php script on your server that reads and saves the given rating.

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=1">
    <img src="star.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=2">
    <img src="star.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=3">
    <img src="star.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=4">
    <img src="star.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/productFooBar/rating?rating=5">
    <img src="star.jpg" />
</a>
```

**Edit:** this is not perfect in any way, but its the only thing that i can think of right now. The biggest problem that I see with this solution is that it uses get parameter, thus making you open for manipulation of ratings. A skilled user could copy the link to the 1-star-rating and vote 1 star as many times as he wants.
Also this will open a tab in the browser. You will have to make a confirmation page to say something like "Thank you for rating one of our products. Click here to go back to our Shop"

**Edit 2:** Using a form is actually a better idea, and it's totally possible, don't listen to ceejayoz. Following code will *replace* the above code. Don't do both ;)

```
<form action="http://mywebsite.com/rating/productFooBar" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" /> ★☆☆☆ <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" /> ★★☆☆ <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" /> ★★★☆ <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /> ★★★★ <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit rating" />
</form>
```

Style this to some extent and your customer will like it. If not, you will have to make it clear to him that one cannot simply use javascript in email, so he will never have such a 'perfect' ratings-plugin like he has in the browser. You can also show him the other approach with the linked images, maybe he finds that better than radiobuttons.

Comment: Can you please check my code once which is mentioned in question?

Comment: @ManeeshRao packing it into a form is actually a very good idea. you can replace the linked images with radiobuttons. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/) is a good example for that

Comment: thanks for the link. But I have already tried this one and implemented it. but my client does't like radio button and he is not happy about that because I am not able to add the style in radio button.

Comment: You know that radio buttons can be styled manually? [Example](https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq), [Example 2](https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/details/BWXbxP)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know radio button can be styled but in email template we can use only inline CSS.

Comment: @ManeeshRao That may be so, but there are tools like [this](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html) to generate a html with inline styles, using separate html and css codes. (I have never used this but i just tested it and it seems to work fine)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will use it and let you know. You are amazing:)